# SQL one to one update

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I am very new in Oracle/PLSQL.

I have a question. I have one to one relationship between two tables. In both tables I have a column named col2. In table 1 this column is null, in the second it is filled. I want to copy all data from one table to another.

```
Example:
Table 1                      Table 2
col1        col2   ...       col1        col2   ...
1           null   ...       1           A      ...
2           B      ...       2           B      ...
3           null   ...       3           C      ...
```

I want it to be:

```
Table 1                      Table 2
col1        col2             col1        col2   ...
1           A      ...       1           A      ...
2           B      ...       2           B      ...
3           C      ...       3           C      ...
```

How can I do that with a Query?

I have tried:

```
UPDATE table 1 SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM table 2 WHERE col1 = '1') WHERE col1 = '1'
```

But it is only for one record. How can I change this query to make it work for whole table?

**Note:** I can not change table structures, can not delete or add new columns, can not use scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge` might be a good choice:

```
merge into table1 a
  using table2 b
  on (a.col1 = b.col1)
when matched then update set
  a.col2 = b.col2;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, can I also add another when clause, say update only when the table 1's col 2 is null, and update only specific col 2's that are for example C in table 2

Comment: You can add another WHEN clause, but that is WHEN NOT MATCHED (and is used for inserting missing rows). What you probably want is a **WHERE** clause which would restrict rows to be updated.

Comment: I have replaced table 2 with a select statement that contains only the rows I need to update, and it worked thanks

Comment: Yes, that's OK too. I'm glad you made it!